# Iterating through a heterogenous container?

Tags: c#, linq

I am trying to iterate over a simple heterogenous container: `Dictionary<string, object>`.

It is constructed like this:

```
var d = new Dictionary<string, object>();
d.Add("key1", "value1");
d.Add("key2", 42);
var sub = new Dictionary<string, object>();
sub.Add("key3", new double[] { 0, 0 });
d.Add("key4", sub);
```

I assumed I could have written a simple function:

```
public IEnumerable<KeyValuePair<string, object>> flatten(IDictionary<string, object> dict)
{
    foreach(KeyValuePair<string, object> item in dict)
    {
        if (item.Value is IDictionary<string, object> subDict)
        {
            flatten(subDict);
        }
        else
        {
            yield return item;
        }
    }
}
```

How can I rewrite the above `flatten` function, so that:

```
var l = flatten(d).ToList();
```

returns a list of three items (with keys: key1, key2 and key3). I have not been able to use `SelectMany` from Linq package in my case so far...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try yield return the results of the `flatten` recursive call:

```
public IEnumerable<KeyValuePair<string, object>> flatten(IDictionary<string, object> dict)
{
    foreach (KeyValuePair<string, object> item in dict)
    {
        if (item.Value is IDictionary<string, object> subDict)
        {
            foreach (var item2 in flatten(subDict))
            {
                yield return item2;
            }
        }
        else
        {
            yield return item;
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want to use `SelectMany`, you actually need to project a non `IDictionary<...>` to an `IEnumerable` (so that the `dict` is *always* thought of as a collection of collections to be flattened):

```
public IEnumerable<KeyValuePair<string, object>> flatten(IDictionary<string, object> dict)
{
   return dict.SelectMany(kv => kv.Value switch {
      IDictionary<string, object> subdict => flatten(subdict),
                                        _ => Enumerable.Repeat(kv, 1)
   });
}
```

#### [Live Demo](https://dotnetfiddle.net/sWxkUl)

We don't need to say `yield return` because `SelectMany` is directly returning an `IEnumerable`